# iOS App crashes in Archive Build but not Release/Run

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-data, uikit

I am getting the following crash log from my app when run from an archived build

```
0 AllPaste 0x000a16c1 AllPaste + 108225
1 AllPaste 0x000a1ad7 AllPaste + 109271
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x38215539 _sigtramp + 48
3 CoreData 0x37321921 -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _processReferenceQueue:] + 940
4 CoreData 0x3737fd0f -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 3046
5 CoreData 0x3730975d -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 452
6 CoreData 0x373e5e51 -[NSFetchedResultsController performFetch:] + 540
7 AllPaste 0x000953e7 AllPaste + 58343
8 AllPaste 0x00095f09 AllPaste + 61193
9 AllPaste 0x000924c3 AllPaste + 46275
10 UIKit 0x31e436b5 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 144
11 UIKit 0x31e438c1 -[UINavigationController viewWillAppear:] + 288
12 UIKit 0x31e436b5 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 144
13 UIKit 0x31e9d1f3 -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 210
14 UIKit 0x31e436b5 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 144
15 UIKit 0x31e9e61b -[UIViewController beginAppearanceTransition:animated:] + 190
16 UIKit 0x31ee4691 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 4076
17 UIKit 0x31f3e461 -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:] + 1732
18 UIKit 0x31ea1af1 -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 756
19 UIKit 0x31ea1af1 -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 756
20 AllPaste 0x0008a9eb AllPaste + 14827
21 CoreFoundation 0x37183435 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 52
22 UIKit 0x31e1c9eb -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 62
23 UIKit 0x31ee23cf -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 118
24 CoreFoundation 0x37183435 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 52
25 UIKit 0x31e1c9eb -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 62
26 UIKit 0x31e1c9a7 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
27 UIKit 0x31e1c985 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
28 UIKit 0x31e1c6f5 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 492
29 UIKit 0x31e1d02d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 476
30 UIKit 0x31e1b50f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 318
31 UIKit 0x31e1af01 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 380
32 UIKit 0x31e014ed -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
33 UIKit 0x31e00d2d _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5808
34 GraphicsServices 0x32e5be13 PurpleEventCallback + 882
35 CoreFoundation 0x371fd553 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 38
36 CoreFoundation 0x371fd4f5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 140
37 CoreFoundation 0x371fc343 __CFRunLoopRun + 1370
38 CoreFoundation 0x3717f4dd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
39 CoreFoundation 0x3717f3a5 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
40 GraphicsServices 0x32e5afed GSEventRunModal + 156
41 UIKit 0x31e2f743 UIApplicationMain + 1090
42 AllPaste 0x00088e97 AllPaste + 7831
43 AllPaste 0x00088e50 AllPaste + 7760`
```

This only happens when I archive and install the app but not when I Run it through Xcode, however both are using the same Ad Hoc build configuration.

Does anyone know why this would be occurring or can identify my error from the log?

Comment: What do you mean by an “archived build”? Do you have a .xcarchive for the build? Where are you reading the crash log/copying it out from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that earlier in the project I had enabled zombies and forgot about it. So that when I was running the simulator and testing on my device it was not detecting a released object. But when I archived build and then shared it into an ipa through the organizer I lost the zombie enabled (of course) and it was not updating the table and throwing my error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are having problems with Core Data. Did you happen to change your data model on the updated app and have an older version of the data model on the device? The crash could be a result of the data models being inconsistent. If that is the case you will need to migrate from the old model to the new one.

Comment: Thanks I found the problem, it was with Core-Data but the issue was I was not updating the table when a new entry was inserted.